Create circular text using fabric js React js
I am trying to make a circular text on fabric js. I just done it by using the path property and now I need to control the radius of the circle I didn't get any Idea after searching on the internet, i s there any methods to control the circular text radius or create a new circular text, I am providing the code below
 useEffect(() => {
    // Update font family of active text object when font state changes

    if (activeText) {
      const getPath = (value: string)=> {
        const path = new fabric.Path(
          value, {
          fill: "transparent",
          hasControls: true
        });
        return path;
      };

      if (transformation === "circle") {
        activeText.set("path", getPath("M 25, 50 a 25,25 0 1,1 50,0 a 25,25 0 1,1 -50,0"));
      }
     
      activeText.set("fontFamily", font);
      activeText.set("fill", textColor);
      activeText.set("opacity", textOpacity);
      activeText.set("stroke", strokeColor);
      activeText.set("strokeWidth", strokeWidth);
      activeText.set("fontSize", fontSize);
      activeText.set("linethrough", line);
      activeText.set("charSpacing", textCharSpacing); //! char spacing is limited to 100
      activeText.set("lineHeight", textLineHeight);
      activeText.set("textAlign", textAlignment);
      activeText.set("underline", textUnderLine);
      activeText.set("fontWeight", textWeight);
      canvasRef.current?.renderAll();
    }
  }, [
    font,
    activeText,
    textColor,
    textLineHeight,
    textOpacity,
    line,
    strokeColor,
    strokeWidth,
    fontSize,
    shadowBlur,
    transformation,
    shadow,
    shadowColor,
    textAlignment,
    textCharSpacing,
    textUnderLine,
    textWeight,
  ]);

